# Converting bytes to java string (possibly kanji)

Tags: java, string, byte

I am trying to convert a byte array to a java string using the following codes:

```
//strInput is a binary string
byte[] bval = new BigInteger(strInput, 2).toByteArray();
strOutput = new String(bval, "UTF-8");
```

I encounter no problem when the target output contains alphanumeric or symbols (e.g. % & * $) only. However, I keep getting an extra NULL character at the beginning of the output when it contains pure japanese characters.

My first guess was maybe it has something to do with signed/unsigned bytes. But when I tried to get the 2s complement of the input, I get garbage characters as output.

Do you guys have other ideas about where that extra NULL character comes from?

------- UPDATE ------
I read somewhere here in stackoverflow that trim() also removes NUL characters aside from whitespace, so I tried that. It has worked well so far for other inputs with japanese characters.

Is this safe to use? 
Or should I really just find an alternative to using BigInteger?

Thanks!

Comment: Please give us a sample binary string. I strongly suspect that using `BigInteger` to parse the data is a bad idea here.

Comment: What is the nature of the byte array? Where does it come from? It would be a hit and miss (more often miss) to convert it properly to a String if it is unknown byte array.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - A sample binary string would be 111001101001110010101100.

Comment: @user1327943: And what Unicode character (or characters) would you want that to represent? (And does that work with your current code?)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I wish to be able to produce normal ascii characters plus japanese characters.

Comment: @user1327943: Yes, but that doesn't say what the example binary string you presented is *meant* to represent - what's the *correct* output for that, and what does your current code do?

Comment: Maybe a Unicode BOM stands in front of the text: `strOutput = strOutput.replaceFirst("\uFFFE", "");`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
byte[] bval= strInput.getBytes("UTF-8");
```